# How to remove this strange visual artifact in the corner of ToolStrip Winforms control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, styling, toolstrip

Here is the picture that shows the problem. Take a look at the bottom right corner.

Anyone knows how to get rid of it?

Setting `LayoutStyle` to `VerticalStackWithOverflow` fixes it but also centers the items horizontally which I don't want.

I just want a vertical stack like in the pic, but without that black line in the bottom right corner.

[image]

Comment: I've always wondered what that little line is all about.

Comment: Glad I am not the only one :O

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the properties bar, set "RenderMode" to "System" or use

```
.RenderMode = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderMode.System;
```

Doing this will change the .BackColor to "Control" but you can change that after if you want.

Comment: I actually checked, it prints the BackColor as using Control before setting it to System and after. So I will change the back color to the same color values.

Comment: Yes but before you change it, the custom rendered uses a slightly different color - or at least appears to - you can see a jarring difference in the look of both. But for what you're doing, I think setting a flat color of your own choosing will not be a problem - and that's only if the container has some overflow. (You might not see the background color at all depending on sizing!)

Comment: Actually just tried but setting the actual values manually doesn't work. Control is set to 240, 240, 240 but doing that does nothing. I assume it realizes there is an already defined color using those values so uses that instead. I set it to 245, 245, 245 and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

Sorry for being late to the party, but the accepted answer didn't work for my needs. The following solution is what I came up with:

### Getting rid of the black line

1) Create a custom renderer:

```
class CustomToolStripProfessionalRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't draw a border
    }
}
```

2) Use the custom renderer:

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new CustomToolStripProfessionalRenderer();
```

### Getting rid of the background

The above solution satisfies the need of the original question, but I didn't like the gradient background on the ToolStrip either. I wanted the ToolStrip to be an "invisible" container:

1) Create a custom color table:

```
class CustomProfessionalColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ToolStripGradientBegin
    {
        get { return SystemColors.Control; }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return SystemColors.Control; }
    }

    public override Color ToolStripGradientEnd
    {
        get { return SystemColors.Control; }
    }
}
```

2) Use the custom color table:

```
class CustomToolStripProfessionalRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public CustomToolStripProfessionalRenderer()
        : base(new CustomProfessionalColorTable())
    {

    }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't draw a border
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your best shot would be to set the `RenderMode` to `System` in the properties and leave the layout properties to `HorizontalStackWithOverflow`.
But that is if you don't mind changing the tooltip paint style.